# Is there a way to develop and test iOS applications for iOS 4.3 up to iOS 6 on the newest XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, xcode4.5

I am starting the development of an iOS Application. One of the main goals for my application is to support as many devices as possible, so after some research I found that I would need my app to be supported on iOS 4.3 and above. I have OSX Mountain Lion and XCode 4.5 which comes with iOS 6.0 SDK and Simulator Pre-Installed.

I have downloaded iOS 5 Simulator from XCode preferences but there is no option to download the iOS 4 Simulator. Are there any workarounds to get the iOS 4 Simulator running on my Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

1. Download a previous version of XCode prior to 4.5.x
2. Mount and open the disk image [.dmg]
3. Select "Go to folder..." command from Finder menu bar and digit the
   path "/Volumes/Xcode and iOS SDK/Packages/"
4. Double-click **iPhoneSimulatorSDKx_x.pkg** [where "x_x" is the version of the iOS Simulator]
5. Click into the destination disk and click on the button "Select folder..."
6. Select your "Developer" folder
7. Start [or restart] XCode

In this way you'll replace the `iOS simulator` in XCode 4.5.x with a previous one. I don't know if this will work tho, because on OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion only iOS Simulator 5.0+ is available. If you really need to test your app[s] with iOS 4.3 [and prior] the best thing you can do is to downgrade OSX to 10.7 and install XCode 4.5.x [or 4.4.x]. By the way I think that testing your apps with iOS simulator 5.0+ is just fine.

Comment: I downgraded to OSX Lion 10.7.5. And I have the iOS Simulators in my XCode now.

Comment: Yup, it's the fastest [and stable] and best way to get iOS Simulator  4.3 I think :-). Good coding! [and testing]

Answer (score 4):

Open the scheme menu(Next to the run and stop buttons), and under the list of simulators/devices, there will be an option, "More Simulators...". You can download all the way down to 4.3 there. However, testing on a simulator is no substitute for testing on a device, and it would be best to get an iPhone or iPod touch with 4.3 installed on it to test.

Comment: I can only see 5.1 and 5.0 Simulators listed there. Check the screenshot http://d.pr/i/l3Rq

Comment: http://d.pr/i/ZwrR It should be there, is your version of XCode completely up to date? Check the documentation selection, maybe you have less libraries downloaded than I do: http://d.pr/i/lVbQ

Comment: You have to be on OSX 10.7 to see iOS Simulator 4.3 in XCode 4.5, on OSX 10.8 only iOS simulator 5.0+ is available

Comment: @Aluminum I am on mountain lion with XCode 4.5. Isn't there any workaround to get the ios4 simulator on my OSX?